# How to use negative padding in css

Tags: html, css

I want to add negative padding in css, I have written a small code of battery charging cell. What I want is if I enter value in negative like -1px than the cell color should move to the left side and div should stay in center.

```css
.cell {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.padding {
  background-color: #3D9970;
  width: 10px;
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 55px;
  padding-right: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cell">
  <div class="cell1"></div>
  <div class="padding"></div><span style="display: inline;"> 
    </div>
```

Please help me.

Comment: can elaborate more what you want to achieve [forget how you already did]

Comment: assume that one side of cell's value is - center is 0 and other side is + 
if someone enter a value of -0.5 than padding should add on left side from center, and if value is entered 1 than 1% padding should added from right side on padding div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

---

See [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#padding-properties):

> Unlike margin properties, values for padding values cannot be negative.

Comment: Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve the same effect with pseudo elements:

```css
.cell{
  display:block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  position:relative;
}
.cell:before{
  content:'';
  background-color: #3D9970;
  width: 10px;
  top:0;
  left:calc(50% - 5px);
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
.cell:after{
  content:'';
  border: 1px solid black;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:block;
  top:0;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="cell">

</div>
```

"Left" property could be negative, so if you change it you can move the position of the green rectangle in the middle (.cell:before) of the block and border itself (.after)

Comment: no bro it's not what i want. i want to add padding on left side and div should stay where it is

Comment: what i want is if i'll add padding left than div should stay in center and padding should be added in left side and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use an **absolute positioning** relatively to a **parent node**. Here the parent node would be the battery "housing".

So you can set the `position` CSS value of the rot div to `relative`, and then the charge one to `absolute`. Indeed, according to [MDN Webdocs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position):

> **`absolute`**: [...] It is positioned relative to *its closest **positioned** ancestor*, if any.

Then, you just have to play with the `left` and `width` CSS properties. For the "middle" case, I chose to display one border.

Below a working snippet. Just click the "Begin the charge variation" button to start the show.

```js
var chargeElement = document.getElementById("charge");

// To set a charge to the battery, simply call: setCharge(percentage)

function setCharge(percentage) {

  var left;
  var width;

  if (percentage > 100) percentage = 100;
  if (percentage < 0) percentage = 0;
  
  chargeElement.setAttribute("data-value", percentage);

  // If the charge is 50%, simply draw a line
  if (percentage == 50) {
    chargeElement.className = "middle";
  } else {
    chargeElement.className = "";
  }

  // Otherwise, adjust left and width values
  if (percentage >= 50) {
    left = 50;
    width = percentage - left;
  } else {
    left = percentage;
    width = 50 - left;
  }

  // Then update the charge style.
  chargeElement.style.left = left + "%";
  chargeElement.style.width = width + "%";

}

// A simple function to add / remove some charge

function addCharge(percentage) {
  var value = parseInt(chargeElement.getAttribute("data-value"));
  value += percentage;
  setCharge(value);
}

// Here just some stuff for illustration.
// You don't need those functions to set the charge.

function letsBeginTheShow(buttonElement) {
  buttonElement.disabled = true;
  setNextCharge(10);
}

function setNextCharge(increment) {
  var percentage = parseInt(chargeElement.getAttribute("data-value"))
  percentage += increment;
  if (percentage > 100) {
    percentage = 100;
    increment = -5;
  }
  if (percentage < 0) {
    percentage = 0;
    increment = 5;
  }
  setCharge(percentage);
  setTimeout(function() {
    setNextCharge(increment);
  }, 50);
}

setCharge(50);
```

```css
.battery {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  /* Below : only for aestethic reasons */
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30px;
  /* End of aesthethic stuff */
}

#charge {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #3D9970;
  border-color: #3D9970;
}

.middle {
  border-left: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="battery">
  <div id="charge" data-value="50" class="middle"></div>
</div>

<button onclick="letsBeginTheShow(this)">Begin the charge variation</button>
```